# Latest selection in multiples different

Tags: selection-tools

Okay, I'm new to Blender and my search has failed so far. Perhaps I just don't know the right terms.
I'm used to CAD programs. When I ctrl-select or shift-click to select multiple vertices or lines in any of those, they're all the same. However, in Blender (at least 2.8) the latest one is white instead of the others' orange, and many alterations seem to not effect it or do so in a very limited manner.
For example, scaling two halves of an edge will move the orange half into the white half, and doesn't move the end of the white one.
What purpose does this serve? And how do I correct it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The item (object or mesh element like vertex, edge or face) in white is considered the [active element](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/pivot_point/active_element.html).

It is generally the "master" whose properties are shown in the UI (properties region sidebar or properties area); and may also be used as the pivot or center of transformations, if selected in the 3D view header.

[image]

Comment: Okay, that actually helps how I think about it, seeing as how things are affected relative to the active object.
Still, is there a way to include it in a selection to adjust it equal to others instead of marking it as the 'baseline'?

Comment: There are four other entries in the illustrated menu

Comment: So there are!
Took me a while to actually find that menu because it doesn't pop out and lacks a label.
Seems at least one of them gets things to act the way I need.
Much appreciated.